# C99: cast callbacks with different number of arguments

Tags: c, function, pointers, casting, c99

in the following example I make a CAST of a function without arguments in a pointer to a function that should receive an argument. Assuming that it gives the desired result, is it possible that this procedure causes some malfunction?
online test: https://onlinegdb.com/SJ6QzzOKI

```
typedef void (*Callback)(const char*);
Callback cb;

void inserisce_cb(void* c) {
    cb=c;
}

void esegue_cb(){
    cb("pippo");
}

void scriveTitolo(const char* titolo) {
    Uart_Println(titolo);
}

void scriveTitolo2() {
    Uart_Println("pluto");
}

void main(){
    inserisce_cb(scriveTitolo);
    esegue_cb();
    inserisce_cb(scriveTitolo2);
    esegue_cb();
}
```

Comment: In general for function pointers in c++ you should use std::function that basically is the same but with type checking and so on.

Comment: Your example won't compile since implicit cast from void to a function pointer is not allowed.

Comment: In C a `void*`pointer is compatible with any pointer to a data object. That does not necessarily mean that it can be used to store a function pointer.

Comment: Oleg Andriyanov: added a cast for c++ compatibility

Comment: Oleg Andriyanov and camp0 : edited the question: restrict to C language

Comment: Well I can't say about C, but in C++ this code clearly involves undefined behavior, since C style cast implies `reinterpret_cast` in this case. And `reinterpret_cast` only allows you to convert object from `void*` back to it's original type, otherwise you can't use it safely other than inspect it's internal byte representation. But in practice it should work (at least for some common ABIs), because this is basically how variable argument lists work: caller pushes arbitrary amount of arguments, and callee is not required to know about how many of them are there on the stack.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the same goes for C — not guaranteed to work, but most probably would.

Comment: You cannot pass a function pointer to a function that takes `void *` as argument. Your code is invalid in C99 regardless of the kind of function pointer you pass. [See here](https://godbolt.org/z/KMxZCE).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converting a pointer to a function to another pointer to a function is defined by the c standard, but using the resulting pointer to call a function with an incompatible type is not, per C 6.3.2.3 8:

> A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a function of another type and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer. If a converted pointer is used to call a function whose type is not compatible with the referenced type, the behavior is undefined.

The declaration `void scriveTitolo2() { … }` defines a function that does not have a parameter type list (it uses the old C style of an identifier list, with that list being empty) and that takes no arguments. A `Callback` pointer points to a function that has a parameter type list and takes a `const char *` argument. These are incompatible per C 2018 6.7.6.3 15:

> For two function types to be compatible,… If one type has a parameter type list and the other type is specified by a function definition that contains a (possibly empty) identifier list, both shall agree in the number of parameters,…

Since they do not agree in the number of parameters, they are incompatible.

The above speaks only to the issue of converting from `void (*)()` to `void (*){const char *)` and using the result to call the function. There is a separate issue in that the function pointer is passed to `inserisce_cb`, which takes an argument of type `void *`, which is a pointer to an object type. The C standard does not define the behavior of converting a pointer to a function type to a pointer to an object type. To remedy this, `inserisce_cb` should be declared to take a pointer to a function type, such as `void inserisce_cb(Callback c)`.

If `scriveTitolo2` can be changed, then the compatibility issue can be resolved by changing it to take a `const char *` parameter that is unused, changing its definition to `void scriveTitolo2(const char *)`.

(Note that it is preferable to declare `scriveTitolo2` with the modern C style, as `void scriveTitolo2(void) { … }`, rather than without the `void`. This is unrelated to the question, as it would not make the function types compatible, but this format of declaration provides more information to the compiler in many circumstances.)

Answer (score 4):

Additional thoughts to Eric's answer, which holds true for C99 as well:

If you call a function with an argument list not compatible to the function's parameter list, this is according to C99 §6.5.2.2 (6) undefined behavior.

It may work, depending on your compiler's ABI. There are compilers that let the called function clean up the stack, other compilers let the caller clean up. The former case will most likely crash, the latter ... who knows.

You can declare your `scriveTitolo2` with an ignored parameter:

```
void scriveTitolo2(const char*) {
    /* ... */
}
```

And everyone is happy: you and the compiler.

Comment: if the second function has the same number of arguments but of different type (and size) eg:

void scriveTitolo2(unsigned char t) {
    if (t==1) printf("paperino"); else printf("pluto");
}

//can it be ok?

Comment: I don't think so, the types have to be compatible. Please read the chapters of the standard.